# Postgres parameters at SQL requests, C#

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I run these commands in a Windows Forms app written in C#:

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("DO $$ BEGIN IF EXISTS(select id from clients where id=@cnumberclient) THEN INSERT INTO reservations(roomnumber,clientnumber,datein, dateout) values(@rnumber, @cnumber, @din, @dout); ELSE raise notice 'HYI'; END IF; END $$;", conn.getConnection());
command.Parameters.Add("@cnumber", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ClientId;
command.Parameters.Add("@cnumberclient", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ClientId;
command.Parameters.Add("@rnumber", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = RoomId;
command.Parameters.Add("@din", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = dateIn;
command.Parameters.Add("@dout", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = dateOut;
```

then I open the connection and execute the command:

```
conn.openConnection();

if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

But I get an error.

> column "cnumberclient" doesn't exist

Postgres doesn't seem to see the parameters
Can you help me?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#positional-and-named-placeholders Maybe put spaces around it, as npgsql has to parse and replace named parameters with positional parameters before sending the query

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `@` symbol from your parameters, that's not part of the parameter name, it's the symbol to identify them in the Sql query.